# Easiest way to get mounts / maximize a monetary investment in LoTRO without sustaining a subscription?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I have several Lord of the Rings Online accounts wherein my children and I play together.  My kids have been beating me up for mounts as a Christmas gift so that we can get around more easily and I'm trying to figure out the most "cost effective" path to take here in order to achieve this goal.

I'm not afraid of spending some money, but I simply cannot see getting stuck, long term, with a monthly bill for this for so many accounts.  I wouldn't mind a one off monthly fee to maximize our gaming experience, nor perhaps a one off expense at acquiring the mounts, however I'm just not sure of the most effective path to follow here.

Further, some of the solutions that I've researched seem a bit dated and I've not found any real clear recent path in these regards.

Could someone provide the best bang for the buck option in this regard with LoTRO?

Comment: You keep [a lot of things](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52958/what-do-you-lose-when-youre-no-longer-a-vip) when you have been a VIP even for just a month. Just a word of advice, if you do this: make sure you get all you need before canceling your subscription. I once took the 3 month subscription with a friend, and canceled it right after. When I logged in a month later, my subscription was gone. So if you take a multi-month subscription, use them all before canceling.

Comment: +1 I'm just starting out again in LotRO so I'm very interested in this too. One problem with Turbine games is that it's not always clear what path you should take to actually purchase something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Samwise Gamgee's Starter Pack** is a great way to get account-wide riding (and other features) very economically.  The pack grants a mount and the riding skill usable immediately upon completing the character's race starting quests.  This is a permanent feature.  All currently created characters get the benefit AND all characters created in the future receive the benefit.  At the time of this writing, the pack was obtainable for $10 (USD).  This makes it less costly than other prior answers.

As a bonus, it also adds 15 inventory slots (1 additional bag) and removes the currency cap.

Furthermore, if the account is not already a premium account or a VIP account, buying this pack converts the account to premium and results in the following associated boosts:

- +1 Character Slot
- 5 Auction House Slots

NOTE: The author has bought and used packs for multiple LOTRO accounts.

NOTE: To use the pack, apply the product code in the in-game LOTRO store.  After applying the code, it may be beneficial to exit the game client and restart it.

NOTE: When applying the product code, automatic conversion to premium may not always succeed, but in this case, the author submitted in in-game support request, and the issue was corrected (and the account converted to premium).

NOTE:  The fact that the pack was a **Turbine** product, or that it may be listed as offered by **Daybreak Games Company** is inconsequential.  It still works even though LOTRO is now operated by **Standing Stone Games**.

References:

- Available on Amazon (limited to two purchases per Amazon account).
- [The Lord of the Rings Online™: Samwise Gamgee's Starter Pack](http://store.turbine.com/store/turbine/en_US/pd/id.ProductDetailsPage/categoryID.58516200/productID.258048600/currency.USD) @ store.turbine.com

Answer (score 6):

My experience with LOTRO was that a one time payment of $20 was all it took to be set up for the life of my characters.  No further investment of cash is necessary.

Why $20?  Because it pays for the [Mithril Edition of LOTRO](http://www.impulsedriven.com/products/ESD-IMP-W2777).  That comes with 4 areas, a mount, and 2000 turbine points.  The turbine points alone are worth the $20.

After that, a Free 2 Play account becomes a Premium account, since you spent actual money on the game.  You start with two character slots, but upon hitting Premium, you get a third character slot... which is like getting another 595 turbine points for free.

Here is where it gets interesting.  If you recognize and acknowledge that turbine points are almost the same as money, since you can purchase them with money... LOTRO virtually pays you for playing the game.  If you perform the deeds in the game, you can earn turbine points.  If you come at this from a broader viewpoint than most people will use, you can actually never spend another dime on the game, and get everything you need.

How?

Take that third new character slot.  Create a tank or DPS based character (Champion, Guardian, Hunter).  This type of character will be easy to play, and require the least investment of time and gear to play well.  Use that character to complete all the deeds in Ered Luin and The Shire.  Continue completing deeds in Bree-Land, avoiding the three deeds in The Barrows that must be done INSIDE of a dungeon (Barrow Wardens, Barrow Spirits, Barrow Spiders).

Now, use one of your other higher level characters to collect reputation items in Angmar (Council of the North, Rangers of Esteledin), Evendim (Wardens of Annuminas), Bree (Men of Bree, Mathom Society), Ered Luin (Thorin's Hall).  Getting 122 of the rep items that give you 700 reputation points will take a character from Neutral to Kindred... and that will earn you 50 turbine points per faction.  The factions I listed have the best drop rates, and that there is 300 turbine points.  Send all those reputation items to your new character (that just did all the deeds).

Let's look at the break down then.

- Ered Luin 130 TP
- The Shire 150 TP
- Bree 155 TP
- Faction Reputation 300 TP
- Total **735 TP**

You then delete that character, make another one, and repeat.

Why deed only in these lands?  These are the starter lands, and most of the slayer deeds require you to kill 90 opponents total ([30 for the basic](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Brigand-slayer_%28Ered_Luin%29) slayer deed, [60 for the advanced](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Brigand-slayer_%28Advanced%29_%28Ered_Luin%29)).  Those two slayer deeds will earn you 15 turbine points total.  If you compare that to one of the Bree-land Barrows deeds I told you to avoid doing, or one of the slayer deeds anywhere else in the game, you are looking at around 360 or more opponents to kill for the same amount of turbine points.  That's [120 kills for the basic](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Wolf-slayer_%28The_Trollshaws%29) deed and [240 for the advanced](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Wolf-slayer_%28Advanced%29_%28The_Trollshaws%29).  In other words, you could end up doing four times the work for the same payout.  In some cases, it is 450 kills per deed combination, in others it might only be twice as many but against much harder opponents.  Only in those three starter areas are the number of kills so low that it is very worthwhile to consider the Turbine Point collection character to be disposable.

Another reason to consider the character to be disposable, is because of the Turbine Points you can collect with reputation items.  You can only collect those Turbine Points once per character, but they are quite lucrative (at 50 TP per faction).  You can get together with a few friends and have them help you grind out all the rep items you need to do it more quickly.

Turbine Points are Account specific, not character specific.  So, points collected with one character are usable across your account.

Now, at 735 Turbine Points per life of the disposable character, you can be purchasing new lands at an alarming rate.  Extras like more bags become easily available.  Expenses like 100 Turbine Points for the Riding Skill are almost laughable expenses.

You want to have multiple accounts?  Simple.  Have your kids log in with you on their accounts, and everyone log into your disposable TP collection characters.  Create a Fellowship and go through all the deeds together.  Not only will it go more quickly, but each player will have to do less work.  You can even have them simply attach their characters to yours (aka right click your icon and choose Follow) and you can do all the work, dragging them through the slayer and exploration deeds.

All that for a single investment of $20 per account, which is cheaper than most games cost today.  If your kids don't intend to play at one time, but rather you want to share a single account, you need only do some work ahead of time and use those collected turbine points to purchase more character slots.  You can purchase a new slot every time you work a new TP collector character.

How do I know?  I've been frivolous with my Turbine Points at times... but I'm a Free to Play player.  I've got my Premium account.  I bought the Mithril Edition from Game Stop when it was $10 in store.  The only land I haven't purchased with Turbine Points earned through these methods, is Great River.  Otherwise, I have every other land in the game including Rohan.  I have all six bags.  All my characters have the riding skill (other than my TP collector, as it is a waste to spend the 100 TP if I am just going to delete the character).  I have opened Trait slots.  I purchased the expanded wallet.  I have six character slots.  Earlier on, I bought recipes.  To reiterate, I never went VIP.  I never purchased a subscription.  The only money I spent, was on the Mithril Edition of the game.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of mounts the way I've optimised is to buy a single month's subscription and quickly level up all five character slots to 20 where they can get the free riding skill by doing the quest at Hengstacer farm.

You usually have more than enough silver to purchase a mount too so this saves spending any Turbine points on riding skill plus mount packages, which must be purchased per character.

If you wanted to play on several servers with different friends then just be quicker with grinding characters up to level 20.

Obviously this is best done when you are starting out playing LotRO rather than once you are an experienced player but I can't think of a more optimal way to get mounts.

Numbers:

If I recall correctly the riding skill plus mount package is 795 Turbine points but the cheapest points package you can buy is 1500 points for approx $20. However, to get riding skill and mounts for three characters you would need to buy the 2500 point package for approx $30.

If you have multiple accounts to sort out you could get three one month subscriptions for $10 each for the same $30 cost and have as many characters with riding skills and mounts as you have time to grind. Definitely a saving.